# How do I make my new website public?

Tags: apache, web, webserver

I have registered a new domain and set nameservers, A-records. I have also added conf files in my sites-enabled and sites-available directories under apache2 directory.

What would be the next step to lead incoming traffic to my appropriate site?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@x.com
ServerName x.com
ServerAlias www.x.com

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "redirect." Do you mean that you have an old domain, y.com, that you want to redirect to x.com?

Comment: No, I have a completely new domain, that if I go to, I go to my default site or whatever

Comment: Did you change your domain name from something else? You make it sound like you want to redirect traffic from your old domain to your newly registered one... But I get the feeling that's not what you're asking

Comment: yeah im beginner that is why

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the document root entry in your virtual hosts file. That is your next step to redirect traffic to your site.

Place this under server alias

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/x.com/public_html
```

Then you put your website in the folder `/var/www/x.com/public_html`. Make sure you modify the access rights so anyone can view the `public_html` contents

Check out this link for further details.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: what about the htaccess file? don't I need it?

Comment: No, not for this

Comment: thanks. one more question. if I have a node.js express app installed in srv/x.com/, am I supposed to make DocumentRoot equal to srv/x.com/ or what is exactly? For security reasons.

Comment: I'm not an expert on node.js, in fact I have never used it, so I'm not sure what to do in such a case. For that you should ask a new question.